# AWS Sending Notifications to a Lambda function in other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to send SNS notifications to a Lambda function from one account to another exposing the lambda through and API gateway. But I'm having an Issue. I first tried with the API Gateway in the same account of the SNS topic and everything worked like a charm but when i try with a topic from other account all I got is a Bad Request Error. Do I need to configure any permission?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable permissions for the TOPIC in another account.

You can find an example in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_Sns.html), section

> Allowing Any AWS Resource to Publish to a Topic